# What object should be passed to serialize () and how to use ViewBag in Knockoutjs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, view, controller

I'm trying to send data from controller to Knockoutjs using a dictionary as explained here: [Sending and Recieving Data between ASP.NET MVC and Knockout.js](http://www.softfinity.com/blog/sending-and-recieving-data-between-asp-net-mvc-and-knockout-js/) but I don't understand which attribute I should pass to serialize.Serialize (????) and how to get the ViewBag.myData in knockoutjs file.

Question1:

Which object should I use here?:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var Data = new Dictionary<String, Object>()
        {
            {"objName1", _objName1Service.GetAsync().Result},
            {"objName2", _objName2Service.GetAsync().Result},
        };

ViewBag.myData = serializer.Serialize(????);
```

Question2:

What is the equivalent of this instruction in Knockout.js?

```
var myData = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.myData);
```

Comment: Take a look at Newtonsoft Json.NET for your javascript-oriented serialization, but for Knockout you should be trying to do some kind of data-binding, associating events like "create" or "delete" or "update" with server-side actions, or "refresh" or "get next page" sort of behavior as well. If you simply want to load your page with the data, you can do sort of what you ask, but it will mostly be done with `data-` attributes in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize your object using some library, like Json.NET (as recommended by Rob G).

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);
```

Send your json object to the View, using `ViewBag`

```
ViewBag.YourJsonObject = output;
```

Print the json object to an html hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenField" value="@ViewBag.YourJsonObject" />
```

Use the html hidden field to set knockout's observable

```
var myData = ko.observable($('#myHiddenField').val());
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation helped me to better understand.